# Determine if there is a path from each vertex to other verticies

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that determines if for each vertex v in a graph there is a path from v to at most twenty other vertices. 
!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is find the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of your graph.  Vertices in the connected components of cardinality at least 20 are the ones you are looking for.

You can use the [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) in a straightforward way to get a really efficient algorithm.

1. Start with each vertex in its own set.
2. For each edge e = { u, v }, union the sets containing u and v.
3. Afterwards, the sets correspond to the connected components.